# MLS QoS to MQC conversion

Tags: cisco, switch, switching, cisco-catalyst, qos

Currently trying to convert MLS QoS to MQC QoS, I'm facing a problem.

In MLS (3750), and auto QoS we have this configuration for INPUT QUEUES:
mls qos srr-queue input bandwidth 90 10

So in input 90% bandwidth for first queue and 10% for second, with VOIP assigned to second queue in my configuration (default MLS Auto QoS).

I would like to convert it in MQC QoS, so I defined this policy map:

```
policy-map PM_BW-IN
      class VOIP
             bandwidth percent 10
      class class-default
             bandwidth percent 90
```

But i can't pass it in an interface as input policy, I got an error.

So, the question is, how convert the mls qos srr-queue input bandwidth 90 10 in MQC ?

Thanks.

Edit with more configuration:

MLS Configuration, the default MLS Auto QoS:

```
mls qos map cos-dscp 0 8 16 26 32 46 48 56
mls qos srr-queue input bandwidth 90 10
mls qos srr-queue input threshold 1 8 16
mls qos srr-queue input threshold 2 34 66
mls qos srr-queue input buffers 67 33 
mls qos srr-queue input cos-map queue 1 threshold 2  1
mls qos srr-queue input cos-map queue 1 threshold 3  0
mls qos srr-queue input cos-map queue 2 threshold 1  2
mls qos srr-queue input cos-map queue 2 threshold 2  4 6 7
mls qos srr-queue input cos-map queue 2 threshold 3  3 5
mls qos srr-queue input dscp-map queue 1 threshold 2  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
mls qos srr-queue input dscp-map queue 1 threshold 3  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
mls qos srr-queue input dscp-map queue 1 threshold 3  32
mls qos srr-queue input dscp-map queue 2 threshold 1  16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
mls qos srr-queue input dscp-map queue 2 threshold 2  33 34 35 36 37 38 39 48
mls qos srr-queue input dscp-map queue 2 threshold 2  49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56
mls qos srr-queue input dscp-map queue 2 threshold 2  57 58 59 60 61 62 63
mls qos srr-queue input dscp-map queue 2 threshold 3  24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
mls qos srr-queue input dscp-map queue 2 threshold 3  40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
mls qos srr-queue output cos-map queue 1 threshold 3  5
mls qos srr-queue output cos-map queue 2 threshold 3  3 6 7
mls qos srr-queue output cos-map queue 3 threshold 3  2 4
mls qos srr-queue output cos-map queue 4 threshold 2  1
mls qos srr-queue output cos-map queue 4 threshold 3  0
mls qos srr-queue output dscp-map queue 1 threshold 3  40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
mls qos srr-queue output dscp-map queue 2 threshold 3  24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
mls qos srr-queue output dscp-map queue 2 threshold 3  48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
mls qos srr-queue output dscp-map queue 2 threshold 3  56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63
mls qos srr-queue output dscp-map queue 3 threshold 3  16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
mls qos srr-queue output dscp-map queue 3 threshold 3  32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
mls qos srr-queue output dscp-map queue 4 threshold 1  8
mls qos srr-queue output dscp-map queue 4 threshold 2  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
mls qos srr-queue output dscp-map queue 4 threshold 3  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
mls qos queue-set output 1 threshold 1 138 138 92 138
mls qos queue-set output 1 threshold 2 138 138 92 400
mls qos queue-set output 1 threshold 3 36 77 100 318
mls qos queue-set output 1 threshold 4 20 50 67 400
mls qos queue-set output 2 threshold 1 149 149 100 149
mls qos queue-set output 2 threshold 2 118 118 100 235
mls qos queue-set output 2 threshold 3 41 68 100 272
mls qos queue-set output 2 threshold 4 42 72 100 242
mls qos queue-set output 1 buffers 10 10 26 54
mls qos queue-set output 2 buffers 16 6 17 61
mls qos
```

The MLS interface configuration:

```
 interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 srr-queue bandwidth share 10 10 60 20
 srr-queue bandwidth shape  10  0  0  0 
 queue-set 2
 mls qos trust cos
 macro description cisco-switch
 auto qos voip trust 
 channel-group 11 mode active
 spanning-tree link-type point-to-point
```

And I want to convert the mls qos srr-queue input bandwidth 90 10 line in MQC configuration.

The policy map exposed in this message doesn't pass as MQC service-policy INPUT of the interface, I got an error.

Comment: Please post the full configuration. Remember to sanitize it.

Comment: You don't really have much control over input to a device. The device is going to receive whatever is sent to it, and it has no control over that. QoS is much better at managing what is sent out from a device. Normally, you classify and mark incoming traffic for outbound treatment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only do Classification/Policing/marking on ingress so you will need to config your policy map as such.

```
policy-map PM_BW-IN
  class VOIP
         police rate percent 10
  class class-default
         police rate percent 90
```

Here is a good [reference](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-3850-series-switches/118629-technote-qos-00.html#anc32) for MLS to MQC conversion for QOS.

Comment: Yeah exactly I know this guide but there wasn't the response about this question. Thanks for this reply.

Comment: So in MLS, what is the meaning of the line mls qos srr-queue input bandwidth 90 10 ?

Comment: For each port, there are 2 input queues so that is specifying the weight/percentage assigned to each queue.